# Is there a deeper relation between Abraham's tale of sacrifice and The Hunted?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, the-hunted

William Friedkin's [*The Hunted*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0269347/) is introduced by a quote spoken by Johnny Cash, in which he gives an interesting rendition of the classic Judeo-Christian tale of Abraham's sacrifice:

> God said to Abraham: "Kill me a son!" Abe says: "Man, you must be puttin' me on." God say: "No!" Abe say: "What?" God say: "You can do what you want, Abe. But the next time you see me comin, you better run." Abe says: "Where do you want this killin' done?" An' god says: "Out on Highway 61."

From which the first line *"God said to Abraham: "Kill me a son!""* reappears at the end of the movie.

Yet I fail to see a clearer connection from that quote or the tale it's based on to the movie's story and themes. There is the notion of L.T. and his failure to be the father figure Hallam searched in him, which might ultimately have led to Hallam's breakdown and killing spree. And L.T. ultimately has to kill Hallam, but that's where the very superficial similarities stop already. Yet, it might as well be Hallam, who's supposed to represent Abraham and L.T. as the god who created him and has to take him down for not trusting in him, but that comparison doesn't really seem to hold much water either. So **is there any more coherent connection between the tale of Abraham, Johnny Cash's rendition of it, or its underlying moral to themes and story of the movie** or was it merely just a "stylish" quote thrown into the mix for the more general and raw emotions it might evoke (whichever those would be)?

Comment: As an aside:  That lyric is from Bob Dylan's [*Highway 61 Revisited*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_61_Revisited_(song)).